# How do I use Try, Catch, and Finally

Tags: vb.net

My assignment is to write a program that asks the user for 10 numbers which it will then find the average of, and must include Try, Catch, and Finally keywords. (Divide by zero exception).

How to I use Try, Catch, and Finally?

So far my program looks like this:

```
Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
            Dim A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M As Integer
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 1st Number: ")
            A = Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 2nd Number: ")
            B = Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 3rd Number: ")
            C = Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 4th Number: ")
            D = Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 5th Number: ")
            E = Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 6th Number: ")
            F = Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 7th Number: ")
            G = Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 8th Number: ")
            H = Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 9th Number: ")
            I = Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 10th Number: ")
            J = Console.ReadLine()
            K = (A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J)
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of numbers to average: ")
            M = Console.ReadLine()
            L = K / M
            Console.WriteLine("The Average Is: " & L)
            Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: [Here some the documentation for Try/Catch/Finally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx).  It has an explanation of what they do and examples of how to use them.

Comment: You have no need for a `finally`, because you're not allocating any resources that need to be disposed. You need a `try..catch` - `try` the division, and add the `catch` to handle the divide by zero error. (Or, more simply, check to make sure `M` is not zero before attempting the division in the first place.)

Comment: @KenWhite The OP specifically said that they *needed* to use `Finally` for their assignment. I'm writing up an answer now so hopefully it's not closed during this time..

Comment: @cybermonkey: Yes, I covered that first in my comment.

Comment: You should turn [`Option Strict On`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) to see some other issues with your code, but by then you will really be struggling to find a reason for Try/Catch. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite - What does `Finally` have to do with disposal of resources?  Finally is just a block of code that will always run, regardless of whether or not there is an exception.  It need not have anything to do with disposal of resources.

Comment: @Chris: In the code written, there is no need for a finally block for anything (with or without a try..catch). *Typically* (note I didn't say *always*) a finally block is used to ensure resources are released such as memory allocations, file handles, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Try`, `Catch`, `Finally` block is extremely useful for handling errors where in a normal instance it would cause the program to crash.

For example:

```
Dim n As Integer
Dim a As Integer = 0
Dim b As Integer = 1
Try
    n = b / a
Catch
    MsgBox("We've crashed :(")
Finally
    MsgBox("..but we're still alive!")
End Try
```

You are also able to get the information on the exact error, a possible use of this is that you might want to filter it out so specific errors are ignored, like per se:

```
Dim n As Integer
Dim a As Integer = 0
Dim b As Integer = 1
Try
    n = a / b
Catch ex As DivideByZeroException
    MsgBox("We've crashed, here's the specific error: " + ex.Message)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Some other error happened: " + ex.Message)
Finally
    MsgBox("..but we're still alive!")
End Try
```

The three parts:

1. `Try`: ***Try*** executing the code within this block, if it fails;
2. `Catch`: ***Catch*** the exception/error and *execute* the code inside this block
3. `Finally`: ***Finally*** execute code inside this block *regardless* of what happened in the `Try` and `Catch` components.

For example you could use something like this for your specific use case:

```
[...]
Try
    L = K / M
    Console.WriteLine("The Average Is: " & L)
    Console.ReadKey()
Catch
    Console.WriteLine("Uh oh, we've divided by 0!")
Finally
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.")
    [...]
End Try
```

The [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx) has some handy information.

As a user who commented on your question said ([Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2278086/mark)), there's other issues with your code (not covering them because it'll go outside the scope of the question) and you should [turn on `Option Strict`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) to see them. Your code could also be made more efficient by utilising a `For` loop and an `Array` or `List`, but I'll leave that to you to do.