# In what situation would Math.Round(..., MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) be preferable to CInt?

Tags: vb.net

Both of the below expressions are `True`:

```
CInt(3.5) = Math.Round(3.5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
CInt(-3.5) = Math.Round(-3.5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

I realize that Math.Round returns a `Double`, but I can always use an `Integer` in the same context even with `Option Strict On`. So, are there situations in which one would want to use `Math.Round(..., MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` instead of the shorter `CInt`?

P.S. There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32806259/2725810) on the same topic (asked by me as well), but that question was badly asked and, as a result, the answers do not address the real question.

Answer (score 1):

In the example given the result is true, but if you change the numbers to 4.5 they are not.

```
CInt(4.5) = Math.Round(4.5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) 'False
```

CInt uses MidpointRounding.ToEven rounding.  If a rounding mode is not provided for Math.Round MidpointRounding.ToEven is used.

The answer is to understand what each method does and to use the appropriate method.

Comment: So, would it be true to say that there is never a good reason to use `Math.Round(..., MidpointRounding.ToEven)` and not `CInt`?

Comment: If you have two methods that do the SAME exact thing, what difference does it make?  IF performance is an issue then pick the faster one.

Answer (score 0):

`CInt(Double)` is compiled to implicit cast that calls the default `Math.Round(Double)` and converts the result to `Integer`, so the main reasons to use `Math.Round(Double, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` instead of `CInt(Double)` would be

- to use the `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` rounding instead of the default `MidpointRounding.ToEven` rounding
- to avoid `System.OverflowException` when the result can't fit in `Integer` (Anything smaller than `Integer.MinValue` or larger than `Integer.MaxValue` such as `Dim d = 2 ^ 31`)
- if `CInt(1.5)` in VB.Net is converted carelessly to `(int)1.5` in C#, small rounding errors might occur. In VB.Net `CInt(1.5)` is 2, but in c# `(int)1.5` is 1.

---

The [CIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) bytecode generated (in VS 2010 .NET 3.5) from

```
Dim d As Double = 2.5

Dim i1 As Integer = CInt(d)             ' 2

Dim i2 As Integer = CType(d, Integer)   ' 2

Dim i3 As Integer = d                   ' 2

Dim d2 = Int(d)                         ' 2.0
```

in [ildasm.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309387) is:

```
  IL_000f:  ldc.r8     2.5
  IL_0018:  stloc.0

  IL_0019:  ldloc.0
  IL_001a:  call       float64 [mscorlib]System.Math::Round(float64)
  IL_001f:  conv.ovf.i4
  IL_0020:  stloc.2

  IL_0021:  ldloc.0
  IL_0022:  call       float64 [mscorlib]System.Math::Round(float64)
  IL_0027:  conv.ovf.i4
  IL_0028:  stloc.3

  IL_0029:  ldloc.0
  IL_002a:  call       float64 [mscorlib]System.Math::Round(float64)
  IL_002f:  conv.ovf.i4
  IL_0030:  stloc.s    i3

  IL_0032:  ldloc.0
  IL_0033:  call       float64 [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.Conversion::Int(float64)
  IL_0038:  stloc.1
```

which shows that the 3 conversions compile to the same call to the default `Math.Round(Double)` and `conv.ovf.i4` Integer conversion.

Comment: What would be an example when `CInt` throws, but `Math.Round` succeeds?

Comment: Anything smaller than `Integer.MinValue` or larger than `Integer.MaxValue` such as `Dim d = 2 ^ 31`. `CInt(2 ^ 31)` will not even compile, but `CInt(2 ^ 31 - 1)` will. Just for reference, `Double.MaxValue` is about 299 times larger than `Integer.MaxValue`