# startIndex cannot be larger than length of string. Parameter name: startIndex vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am working with a scale software using COM Port . i found COM port but the data is not coming from machine . help me to get data from machine. Note: Machine is connected to computer through COM port

> startIndex cannot be larger than length of string

Please read comments which I think they can help you.
This is the code:

```
Private Sub FrmScalWeight_all_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.TxtPDate.Text = Date.Now.Date '
    'Me.TxtUserID.Text = FrmUser_LogIn.TxtUser_Id.Text
    'TxtVoucherNo_auto.Visible = False
    Call Pending_car()




    Try


        '---Scale
        'When our form loads, auto detect all serial ports in the system and populate the cmbPort Combo box.

        myPort = IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames() 'Get all com ports available
        cmbBaud.Items.Add(9600)     'Populate the cmbBaud Combo box to common baud rates used   
        cmbBaud.Items.Add(19200)
        cmbBaud.Items.Add(38400)
        cmbBaud.Items.Add(57600)
        cmbBaud.Items.Add(115200)

        For i = 0 To UBound(myPort)
            cmbPort.Items.Add(myPort(i))
        Next

        cmbPort.Text = cmbPort.Items.Item(0)    'Set cmbPort text to the first COM port detected
        cmbBaud.Text = cmbBaud.Items.Item(0)    'Set cmbBaud text to the first Baud rate on the list

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Comport not found.")
    End Try


    btnDisconnect.Visible = False
    btnConnect.Enabled = True


End Sub

Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String)
    'compares the ID of the creating Thread to the ID of the calling Thread
    If Me.TxtWeight.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
        Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
    Else
        Me.TxtWeight.Text &= [text]

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnConnect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnConnect.Click
        Me.TxtWeight.Text = ""


        Try


            SerialPort2.PortName = cmbPort.Text         'Set SerialPort1 to the selected COM port at startup
            SerialPort2.BaudRate = cmbBaud.Text         'Set Baud rate to the selected value on 

            'Other Serial Port Property
            SerialPort2.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
            SerialPort2.StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
            SerialPort2.DataBits = 8            'Open our serial port
            SerialPort2.Open()

            btnConnect.Visible = False          'Disable Connect button
            btnDisconnect.Visible = True        'and Enable Disconnect button



        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
     Private Sub btnDisconnect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDisconnect.Click

      Me.TxtWeight.Text = Me.TxtWeight.Text.Substring(2, 6) ' error occurs here
        SerialPort2.Close()             'Close our Serial Port
        btnConnect.Visible = True
        btnDisconnect.Visible = False


        '---
        Call Weight()

   End Sub
```

Comment: What else did you expect to happen? Please come back when you've read about variable assignment.

Comment: Like @bob said, what *did* you expect that line to do? If you told us that, we might be able to answer your question properly.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`TxtWeight` is `""` (so, `nil`) because it doesn't exist yet- all the declaration does is reserve the space in the memory but doesn't assign anything.

I'm unsure what you're trying to do here, and I suspect there's more to the code that you haven't posted (*so please post it and I'll update my answer*).

Basically what you're doing is making `TxtWeight` equal nothing, and then expecting to assign `Me.TxtWeight.Text.Substring(2, 6)` (which fails because there's nothing there).

You need to assign something to it before doing that, or [alternatively formulate a `Try..Catch` block (see my answer linked here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27870620/how-do-i-use-try-catch-and-finally/27870908#27870908)  to catch the error so your program doesn't crash.

Comment: I have tried everything. i think there is a problem in my machine.

Comment: After several downvotes (& them being reversed): **please vote on the merits of my answer, *not* the question**.